# New Laptop slows/freezes when using applications

Tags: hard-drive, performance

At first I thought it was a RAM issue (which in retrospect was silly)

Here is a picture of my resource monitor when the freezing happens

[image: pic]

So it seems to be a problem with the Disk (Disk Queue?). It's possible that I'm over working my computer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How much virtual memory is allocated? Large pagefile size can hurt performance, because the OS will use the much slower HDD more frequently. On my PC's, I've manually set the minimum and maximum pagefile to no larger than RAM, or even 1/2 RAM with large RAM cards.